# How to create continuous flat shadow of text in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know this is super easy to do, but I can't find a way to drop this type of shadow thing in photoshop. Something like this:

[image]

Can anyone help to achieve this type of text effect shadow?

I approached this stepwise:
1. Written a text
2. Created a white rectangle layer behind text.
3. Ctrl + click on text layer, created text marquee and deleted the same text from from white rectangle.
4. Been trying with perspective transform, but could move any further.

I'm stuck with something like this.

[image]

Comment: Anyone there to help ?

Comment: Great! Your Q will be automatically nominated for re-opening. Let the answers come! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd method on the page you posted is probably going to be the winner for you, but there are ways to 'cheat'.  Whichever way you do it you could take some short-cuts, though they do come with a price.

Firstly, we have to take into account that we're using vanishing point perspective.  For this we need to decide on the vanishing point. For upper case text this will be simple... Or will it?  Bear in mind that characters in fonts are not necessarily all the same height...

[image: Character heights]

Now convert our text to shapes. Then we need to make a copy of the shape text (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Drag the text)...

[image: Convert to shapes]

Select the *Background* layer and (so long as the document bounds snap setting is ticked) you should be able to drag guides from your rulers which will snap to the centre width and height of the current image. These crossed guides will become our vanishing point (VP). In reality we don't have to have the guides crossing in the centre of the document, they can cross anywhere. Now, using the **Move Tool** move the converted text shape on to the guides so that the centre of the shape snaps to the crossed guides:

[image: Snap shape to guides]

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** either move or delete the anchor points around the outside of each letter furthest from the vanishing point. As an example, consider the first **T** shape. Choose one of the anchor points not on the closest edges to the VP and drag it to the VP (it should snap into place):

[image: Drag the vertices to the VP]

Now right-click and delete the other anchor points...

[image: Delete the other anchor points]

...until you have just those closest to your VP:

[image: Finished first letter]

Now repeat this process for your other letters. Some letters will require more work than others. In the example I've shown you I found the S, second E and R required a bit more thought than the others.

[image: All letters done]

Remember we kept a copy of our letters, earlier, now we can use them to cut our shapes out. Notice, here, I've given them a different colour to the shadow we've just been working with:

[image: Original lettering]

There are a couple of errors here and there, but these can be tidied up as you go, for instance, I've missed the VP shadow from the top of the second T.

The process I've described gives a VP shadow for solid characters. If you want to make the shadow characters transparent, as you have in your original post, then you'll need to be a little destructive (uh-oh!) with the shape you've just been working on.

Select your shadow shape and **Rasterise** it:

[image: Rasterise]

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click the front text shape (the red text in my image) in the layers panel so you get the marquee around the text shape.

[image: Selected text]

Select the shadow text layer and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to clear that area:

[image: Finally]

The whole process was pretty involved and not something I'd like to do frequently. Personally I'd rather take a snap-shot of one of the effects from another package and simply paste it into Photoshop and trace the points around - far easier.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Here is my result, but I will keep on trying to get clean and desired effect. http://imgur.com/4i7rqU9

Comment: @g13: I would mark Luciano's answer as correct - it requires the least work. I don't seem to have this option in PS-CS6.

Comment: yes, it is easy, but I'm stuck at one point, and can't move further. Therefore, I marked your solution.

Comment: Hey @Paul, Is there any proper name for this type of shadow effect?

Comment: @g13: It's simply a vanishing point perspective shadow AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 3D Extrude tool to get that result.

- Create your text
- Duplicate the text layer
- 3D > New 3D Extrusion from Selected layer
- In the 3D panel, select your object.

[image]

- In Properties Panel, deselect "Cast Shadows" and "Catch Shadows". Set the Extrusion Depth to 2500 (you can play with the value here)

[image]

- Back in the 3D panel, Shift+click all the Material inside the object.
- In the Properties panel, click the Diffuse color and set intensity to +20 stops

[image]

- you will end up with this:

[image]

- Now Ctrl+select the Text layer, and use that selection as a mask on the 3D extruded layer. You should end with this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Luciano, I don't get where to set intensity +20 stops. Can you tell where is it located?

Comment: Which version of PS are you using, Luciano?

Comment: @paul, it is extended cs6 version of photoshop.

Comment: indeed, CS6 extended. My bad if it's not possible in the non-extended version...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

- Type your text
- Create a white rectangle behind it
- Transform your text into a pixel layer
- Crtl + clic on the icon of the text in order to get a selection from the outline
- Use the eraser on the white rectangle while keeping the selection.

**PS** : I'm French. We call that concept "centre de perspective" which I can't translate better than "perspective center". Be comprehensive, please :)

In your image, the perspective is directed towards the center. If you are going to delete or fill some part, you have to make sure to respect that. Look at the S, it's at the far right of the perspective, so the white parts on its right is deleted, and its left is still in white. Same goes for the first R, which is a the far left, so it's inverted. Then, with the second R, which is right in the middle, you will not find these, because of its position in the center perspective. This image show the center of perspective I choose :

[image]

Now, we have to delete some part of the image. I'm making this quick + using GIMP, so it will not be perfect but usefull to understand.
Using this center, I'm going to cut thought the white spaces :

[image]

As you can see, i cropped the top of the space between the R & the A, as well as the bottom of the A. Just repeat everewhere it's needed ; your example doesn't crop the white space inside a letter, so it can be readable.

Be carefull not to crop too much, otherwise your text will not be readable. For a better result, you should use a better typo than mine and reduce space between letters

Comment: Thanks, for reply and effort. Being newbie, it would be better if you can guide with visuals.

Comment: I edited my answer, i just can't comment your question (not enough reputation)